# Getting Coordinates from Selenium IDE

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, gui

I am trying to work with the Selenium IDE on Firefox. I was wondering does anyone know a way to get an element's/widget's coordinates directly from the IDE? Is there an add-on or some option that already exists? At the moment it is not providing me with enough information for each thing I click on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/), which is an Add-on of firefox.

After installation, perform following:

1. Click on Miscellaneous and select `Display Line Guides`
2. Click on `Add Horizontal Line Guide` button to add the horizontal line to get the Y Coordinate of Element and Click on `Add Vertical Line Guide` button to add Vertical line to get the X coordinate of Element
3. scroll horizontal/vertical line such that the element's position comes to the intersection of the lines.
4. Select Lines to see the coordinates just right to the `Add Vertical Line Guide` button